# Build servers support for SSH and Https protocols

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh, https, build

We have build servers ( windows and linux machines ) for CI process. So far we have used SSH protocol supported customized version control for storing the code.

We are in a process migrating code from our customized environment to enterprise code repository solution which will be supporting only Https due to security concerns in our company.

I know we can use windows machines ( build server) with https protocol for CI .  I am not completely sure about linux machine (build server)..Can we use Linux build server with Https protocol..Is it a standard way?

Thank you All

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create your own SSL certificates and setup your own Certificate Authority for internal company use.
https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/

Comment: Thank you for the answer